# Search with the supplied value in the current and all successive parents when both child and parent are stored in the same table using JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, criteria-api

I have two entities:

Influence details mapped as OneToOne with aggregators

```
/**
 * @author MalkeithSingh on 27-08-2019
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "INFLUENCE_DETAILS")
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy.class)
public class InfluenceDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;



    @Column(name = "influence_summary_id", length = 64)
    private Long influenceSummaryId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "aggregator_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "agg_id",
                updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private QualityAggregator aggregators;



    @Column(name = "rule_id", length = 64)
    private String ruleId;

    @Column(name = "rule_desc", nullable = false)
    private String ruleDesc;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;
```

Entity 2:
And QualityAggregators. A quality aggregator can have another aggregator as a parent which can again have a parent and so on.
Hence a child parent relationship in the same table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "QUALITY_AGGREGATOR")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy.class)
@Builder
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class QualityAggregator {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "agg_id")
    private String aggId;

    @Column(name = "project_id")
    private String projectId;

    @Column(name = "job_id")
    private String jobId;

    @Column(name = "job_instance_id")
    private String jobInstanceId;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date timestamp;

    @Column(name = "agg_key")
    private String aggKey;

    @Column(name = "agg_value")
    private String aggValue;

    @Column(name = "level")
    private Integer level;

    @Column(name = "parent_agg_id")
    private String parentAggId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_agg_id", referencedColumnName = "agg_id",insertable = false,updatable = false)
    private QualityAggregator parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private Set<QualityAggregator> children;
```

Note:- The last child in the aggregators table is mapped to the influence detail table.

Now what i want to do is to get all InfluenceDetails where both the agg_key and agg_value in the mapped child aggregator or in any of it parents matches the supplied value.

This is what I have so far. I am not aware of how many levels the aggregators might have so I take default 5 and have made the property configurable. But there has to be a better way.

```
public class InfluencerDetailsSpecification {

    @Value("{no.of.aggregators}")
    private Integer aggregators;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        setNoOfAggregators(aggregators);
    }

    private static Integer noOfAggregators = 5;

    /**
     * Creates a query for searching in aggregators and all its successive parents upto the no of levels specified(Defaults to 5)
     * @param request list of AggregatorsRequest to be searched
     * @return The prepared specification
     */
    public static Specification<InfluenceDetails> findByAggregators(List<AggregatorsRequest> request) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            Join<InfluenceDetails, QualityAggregator> lastChild = root.join("aggregators");

            Function<AggregatorsRequest, Predicate> toPredicate = agg -> {
                List<Predicate> listOfOrPredicates = new ArrayList<>();
                Join<QualityAggregator, QualityAggregator> parent =  lastChild.join("parent",JoinType.LEFT);
                Predicate p0 = cb.and(cb.equal(lastChild.get("aggKey"), agg.getAggKey()), cb.equal(lastChild.get("aggValue"), agg.getAggValue()));
                listOfOrPredicates.add(p0);
                Integer aggsNos = Integer.valueOf(noOfAggregators);
                while(aggsNos-- > 2){
                    listOfOrPredicates.add(cb.and(cb.equal(parent.get("aggKey"), agg.getAggKey()), cb.equal(parent.get("aggValue"), agg.getAggValue())));
                    parent = parent.join("parent",JoinType.LEFT);
                }
                return cb.or(listOfOrPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[listOfOrPredicates.size()]));
            };
            return cb.and(cb.or(request.stream().map(toPredicate).toArray(Predicate[]::new)));
        };

    }

    public static Integer getNoOfAggregators() {
        return noOfAggregators;
    }

    public static void setNoOfAggregators(Integer noOfAggregators) {
        if(Objects.isNull(noOfAggregators))
            noOfAggregators = 5;

        InfluencerDetailsSpecification.noOfAggregators = noOfAggregators;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no way of doing it efficiently with Criteria API. You'll want to use the hierarchical query capabilities provided by your RDBMS instead (e.g. `WITH RECURSIVE` or `CONNECT BY`)

Comment: Ya that is option. I can recursively query with the supplied values in the aggregator table to find the leaf node and then search with the aggId in the InfluenceDetails table. But that will involve two different steps. That's why I was looking for a way to do it using criteria in one go. If there is no other option then I will do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the recursive "one step" solution. I implemented it with [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA):

```java
public List<InfluenceDetails> getDetailsByAggregator(String aggKey,
                                                     String aggValue) {
    FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((InfluenceDetails details) -> {

        QualityAggregator relevantAgg = subQuery((QualityAggregator it,
                                                  QualityAggregator agg,
                                                  QualityAggregator child) -> {
            SELECT(agg);
            FROM(agg);
            WHERE(agg.getAggKey() == aggKey && agg.getAggValue() == aggValue);

            UNION_ALL();

            SELECT(child);
            FROM(child).JOIN(recurseOn(it)).ON(child.getParent() == it);
        });

        WITH(RECURSIVE(relevantAgg));

        // DISTINCT removes possible dups
        SELECT(DISTINCT(details));
        FROM(details).JOIN(relevantAgg).ON(details.getAggregators() == relevantAgg);
    });

    return query.createQuery(em, InfluenceDetails.class).getResultList();
}
```

this produces the following SQL:

```
WITH RECURSIVE q0  AS 
(SELECT t2.* 
FROM QUALITY_AGGREGATOR t2 
WHERE ((t2.agg_key = ?1) AND (t2.agg_value = ?2)) 
UNION ALL  
SELECT t3.* 
FROM QUALITY_AGGREGATOR t3  INNER JOIN q0 t1  ON (t3.parent_agg_id = t1.agg_id) )

SELECT DISTINCT t0.*  
FROM INFLUENCE_DETAILS t0  INNER JOIN q0  ON (t0.aggregator_id = q0.agg_id)
```

Explanation of the [WITH RECURSIVE](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/Common-Table-Expressions).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will look into into Fluent Jpa